# My child container isn't justifying to the left when flexbox is in column direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a flexbox with writing in one and an image in the other and they are inline when over 1100px. The writing justifies to the left when over 1300px but centres when below 1300px. The problem this causes is that I have a javascript element embedded which causes the writing to type some words and when centred the whole container moves which makes it harder to read the writing. I've tried multiple ways to try justify the writing to the left but I can't seem to find the problem.

```js
/* ------ navbar toggle ------ */
let menuIcon = document.querySelector('#menu-icon');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');

menuIcon.onclick = () => {
  menuIcon.classList.toggle('bx-x');
  navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};

/* ------ active link for scroll section ------ */
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('header nav a');

window.onscroll = () => {
  sections.forEach(sec => {
    let top = window.scrollY;
    let offset = sec.offsetTop - 150;
    let height = sec.offsetHeight;
    let id = sec.getAttribute('id');

    if (top >= offset && top < offset + height) {
      navLinks.forEach(links => {
        links.classList.remove('active');
      });
      document.querySelector('header nav a[href*=' + id + ']').classList.add('active');
    };
  });
  /* ------ sticky navbar ------ */
  let header = document.querySelector('header');
  header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 100);

  /* ------ remove navbar toggle when clicked ------ */
  menuIcon.classList.remove('bx-x');
  navbar.classList.remove('active');
};


/* ------ scroll reveal ------ */
ScrollReveal({ 
    reset: true,
    distance: '80px',
    duration:2000,
    delay:150,
});

ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content, .heading', {
  origin: 'top'
});
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-img, .about-img, .projects-box, .contact form', {
  origin: 'bottom'
});
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content h3', {
  origin: 'left'
});
ScrollReveal().reveal('.home-content h1, .about-content', {
  origin: 'right'
});


/* ------ typed js ------ */
const typed = new Typed('.multiple-text', {
  strings: ['Engineering Student', 'Aspiring Software Engineer'],
  typeSpeed: 100,
  backspeed: 500,
  backDelay: 1000,
  loop: true,
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

:root {
  --bg-color: #1f242d;
  --second-bg-color: #323946;
  --text-color: #fff;
  --main-color: #0ef;
}

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  background: var(--bg-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 160px 10% 32px;
}


/* --------- Header --------- */

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 32px 9%;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header.sticky {
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.logo {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: default;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  margin-left: 44px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.navbar a.active {
  color: var(--main-color);
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  display: none;
}


/* --------- Home --------- */

.home {
  padding: 160px 5% 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.home-img img {
  width: 30vw;
}

.home-img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.home-content h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.home-content h3:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

span {
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.home-content h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: var(--main-color);
}

.social-media a {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0.2rem solid var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: var(--main-color);
  margin: 48px 24px 48px 0;
}

.social-media a:hover {
  background: var(--main-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px var(--main-color);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 45px;
  background: var(--main-color);
  border-radius: 64px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px var(--main-color);
}

@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  html {
    font-size: 55%;
  }
  section {
    padding: 160px 3% 32px;
  }
  .footer {
    padding: 32px 3%;
  }
  .projects {
    padding-top: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
  }
  .projects h2 {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .projects-layer h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .projects-layer p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 5px 0 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  #menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 3%;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar.active {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .home {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .home .home-content h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .home-content h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  .home-img img {
    width: 50vw;
    margin-top: 48px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo"><span>My</span>Portfolio</a>
  <i class='bx bx-menu' id="menu-icon"></i>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="home-content">
    <h3>Hello, It's Me</h3>
    <h1>Insert</h1>
    <h1>Name here</h1>
    <h3>And I'm an <span class="multiple-text"></span></h3>
    <div class="social-media">
      <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-linkedin'></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-linkedin'></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class='bx bxl-linkedin'></i></a>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn" download="CV">Download CV</a>
  </div>
  <div class="home-img">
    <img src="./8 - fixing tp.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Libraries -->

<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@900&family=Space+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: _"and when centred the whole container moves which makes it harder to read the writing"_ - so give the container an appropriate width, at which it will be able to contain the longest word ...?

Comment: @CBroe the width is enough to fit the container. All the writing moves due to the fact there's some javascript which types multiple words. So when the element is centred, it pushes everything to the left

Comment: The width of `.home-content` is exactly as much as its content requires, so of course it will "jump around" if you have it centered, and the content width changes. So _give_ it a width, instead of letting it get an automatic one.

Comment: @CBroe okayy got you. I set the width to 100% and it worked. Thank you